# Problem with controlled rotation in HHL

Tags: hhl-algorithm

In HHL algorithm, for subroutine involving controlled rotation, after applying $R_y(\theta)$, where $\theta=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{C}{\lambda}\right)$ to the ancilla, the state changes to $\sqrt{1-\frac{C^2}{\lambda^2}}|0\rangle+\frac{C}{\lambda}|1\rangle.$

**Question**

If $\lambda=1$, then by $\sqrt{1-\frac{C^2}{\lambda^2}}|0\rangle+\frac{C}{\lambda}|1\rangle$ and choosing $C=1$, we get $\theta=\pi$. For $\lambda=2$, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}.$ So in general, for each $\lambda$, correspondingly there's a different $\theta$. Since we don't know eigenvalues a priori,  how do we account $\theta $s for superpositon of eigenvalues?

With respect to the circuit [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2232v2.pdf) on page 5, I don't understand how the controlled rotation part works. Will this circuit work when I choose a hermitian matrix $A_{4\times 4}$ such that, one of it's eigenvalues, $\lambda_j=10\neq 2^i,i \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: There are too many questions here. Please ask one question per post, as it will help us give you better answers.

Comment: How I remember, the circuit in the paper (Fig.4) is working only for (1) matrix from the same paper. The more generic solution/circuit is proposed in other figures of the same paper.

Answer (score 4):

You don't know the eigenvalues *a priori*, but you have performed phase estimation, and have (at least a good approximation to) your eigenvalues recorded on a register. If you control off that register, you can use it to decide the angle of the rotation for each eigenvector.

Comment: The state of register after phase estimation will be superposition of all the eigenvalues of matrix A. We use it as control rotation to ancilla. I don't understand that how do we decide the angles of rotation?

Comment: No, it's entangled with the input state. So if the eigenvectors of $A$ are $|\lambda_i\rangle$, then the input state is decomposed as $\sum_i\alpha_i|\lambda_i\rangle$, then after phase estimation on $t$ qubits, you have $\sum_i\alpha_i\lambda_i\rangle|\theta_i\rangle$, where $\theta_i$ is the best approximation to $e^{2\pi\theta_i/2^t}=\lambda_i$. If you do a controlled rotation off the $|\theta_i\rangle$ part, that you can say "if the angle is $\theta_i$, do rotation $R_y(f(\theta_i))$ where $f$ is some extra calculation you might perform.

Comment: Please also have a look at this question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11347/rotations-to-encode-fx-into-ancilla-qubit-for-quantum-monte-carlo?noredirect=1#comment14624_11347 and in particular my comments after the question.

Comment: In this case is $f(\theta_i)=arcsin(\frac{2C}{\theta_i})$? If yes, how do we compute it?

Comment: How would you compute it on a classical computer?

Comment: I don't know. I tried to look it on web, but didn't find anything.

Comment: My point is that there is a way that you can calculate it on a classical computer, even if the translation from high-level programming language to a sequence of logical operations is absolutely awful (and I don't know what it actually *is*, just that it exists). So, you find that circuit and you translate it into a reversible set of logic gates, and you can implement that same set of logic gates on a quantum computer.

Comment: looks like the taylor series expansion of arcsin isn't too bad, assuming you know how to implement addition,multiplication in your circuit this shouldn't be a challenge: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+arccos&lk=3

Answer (score 0):

The question of how the eigenvalue inversion subroutine is implemented in general is not solved yet in a satisfactory way, to my knowledge. I myself spent quite some time looking for the classical algorithm implemented in classical computers to try to make it reversible, but even that was lost time. What I am aware of is that [Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.py) has its own implementation (although I don't know how general it is), and that there are some papers that propose/implement approximations of the inversion function. For instance, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.11463) implements an approximation of the eigenvalue inversion subroutine (the code in `Quil` can be found in [the associated GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/apozas/bayesian-dl-quantum/-/blob/master/HHL_Rigetti.py#L168)) that is exact in the case of eigenvalues that are powers of 2. The reason why it is exact for powers of 2 is because in that case the inversion can be written as a combination of bit swaps, so the eigenvalue inversion subroutine is a collection of controlled SWAP gates (a pictorial representation of the circuit is in Fig. 3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2485)). It is however very unlikely that this algorithm can be improved further without a huge increase in qubit count, since the next step of the iteration (Fig. 4 in the last paper cited) has an output very nonlinear in the input.