# How to construct a multi-qubit controlled rotation with variable angle?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, qiskit, circuit-construction

I'm trying to construct a circuit that performs the quantum transformation :

[image]

Where $f$ is some function. Is there a way to do it without going through every possible value of $i$ ?

Comment: This has essentially been asked before. You probably want to take a look at my answer here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/10282/1837

Comment: @DaftWullie Okay, I figured it out, thanks